# Probability of picking out balls of three different colours

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem**

> A bag contains $3$ red balls, $4$ green balls and $5$ blue balls. Compute the probability of picking out three balls of different colours, without replacement.

**Possible solution**

I compute the different combinations: RVB, RBV, VRB, VBR, BRV and BVR. Each one has probability $\frac{1}{22}$. Therefor I thought that the total probability was $6\cdot\frac{1}{22}$. Is my solution correct or completely wrong?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Lorenzo Fabbri - San Marino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct.  Those are disjoint probabilities and can be added.  They cover all the ways to get one of each color.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. One last thing: is it possible to "clean" the computation (without doing all these calculations)?

Comment: I'm not sure how obvious it is that all six orders have the same probability.  It is true.  That would save you computing each one.